# What's a simple way to flatten a dynamic object?

Tags: c#

I have a ToJson method which performs the following:

```
public object ToJson()
{
    return new
        {
            attr = new
                {
                    id = ID,
                    entityID = EntityID,
                    rel = Type.GetDescription().ToLowerInvariant(),
                    additionalAttributes = AdditionalAttributes
                },
            data = new
                {
                    title = Title,
                    icon = IconPath
                }
        };
}
```

It's no good for me to have AdditionalAttributes be at a lower level than the rest of the properties. I would like to flatten its properties into the same level as id, entityID and rel.

For example, if AdditionalAttributes is:

```
subcomponentNode.AdditionalAttributes = new
    {
        count = subcomponent.Count
    };
```

then I would hope for attr to consist of id, entityID, rel and count.

I'm not expecting any conflicting attribute names. If there are conflicts, merging or ignoring is OK -- whichever is easier to support.

Is this a trivial operation in C#? I can achieve it like this, but it feels a bit dirty:

```
dynamic attr = AdditionalAttributes;
attr.id = ID;
attr.entityID = EntityID;
attr.rel = Type.GetDescription().ToLowerInvariant();
```

Comment: I think I'd use a non-anonymous class and make AdditionalAttributes' type `object`. Making everything anonymous may be useful at times, but you already have an object you can never deal with outside this method, because you won't have the anonymous type to cast it back into. C# is a strongly typed language. Treating it as if it isn't one can really bite you if you aren't careful.